# Record Android Screen Problem Using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, record

When I press on vertical ellipsis
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBW0k.png)
It show me this window, So I press on Start Recording
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mtzr.png)
Then it show me this error
[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOBhL.png)
How can I solve this problem?

record the screen on my Emulator
[Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf7o7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bad solution.

But if you need a fast solution. Record the whole screen and crop it so you can only see what you really care about.

Answer (score 0):

Did you allow the permission to the camera in you'r `manifest.xml`

must add this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Yes, but it is not working

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to record you'r emulator screen ? And from the picture you give you are using AMD hardware in you'r computer in this case did you install the amd sdk in Tools->SDK Manager -> SDK TOOLS

Answer (score 0):

Check out this cli tool: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy
It works very fast and you can record the screen directly to video file with command:

```
scrcpy --record=file.mp4
```